# How to run a file (e.g. AVI) from a C# app

Tags: c#, external

I would need my app to just run any file in a player/browser that Windows use (so for AVI it would use e.g. BSPlayer or whatever has the PC set etc.).
All I found was related to EXE files.

EDIT: I do not mean just multimedia files. I mean also TXT (where I would expect Notepad to open etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Process.Start(System.String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx) to start the default application for a file type.

For example:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\MyFile.txt");
```

Or

```
Process.Start(@"D:\Videos\Films\SomeFilm.avi");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DirectX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh452744) for that.

From the [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/53d1071b-26d9-406a-877c-3b33eedf8a4c/playing-avi-files-on-c-form?forum=winforms) forum

```
//create the video
Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video video = new Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video(fileName);
//set the System.Windows.Forms.Control to play it in (e.g a panel)
video.Owner = panel1;
//Play the video (put this in a buttons click event)
video.Play();
//Pause the video (put this in a buttons click event)
video.Pause();
//Stop the video (put this in a buttons click event)
video.Stop();
```

Also check [Playing Audio and Video Files Using C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/e628d9/playing-audio-and-video-files-using-c-sharp/)

**EDIT:**

You may try this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"yourfilewith a path");
```

to start the application.

A sample example:

```
String fileToOpen = "C:/test.avi";
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo ps = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("C:/Program Files/Windows Media Player/wmplayer.exe", fileToOpen);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ps);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not mean just multimedia files. I mean also TXT (where I would expect Notepad to open etc.)

Comment: @user970696:- For opeining a text file you simpy need Process.Start(@"C:\somefile.txt");

Comment: You gave the best answer on the initial question. Please update with comment to reflect current rewrite of the question. +1 nevertheless.

Comment: @user970696:- Updated my answer. Initially I thought you were specific with .avi files so gave the answer for that! :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a console/windows application best to use

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("your file path and file extension");
```